# Django: Getting a Model type when Using a Defer Query

Tags: python, django, django-models

When you use the `defer(...)` query command, Django returns a different class than your original model.  How can you dynamically get the model's name when using the defer field?

In code:

```
obj_nodefer = model_class.objects.filter(title="foo")[0]
model_name = str(type(obj_nodefer)) # Works just fine

obj_defer = model_class.objects.filter(title="foo").defer("content")[0]
model_name = str(type(obj_defer)) # Does't return the right name because of defer above.
```

How do I get the model's name from `obj_defer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the non-deferred model, do

```
t = type(obj)
if t._deferred:
  t = t.__base__
```

Comment: The `t.__base__` does not work for me, but I'm running an old version of django (v1.3).  Was that added in a more recent version?

Comment: I'm running 1.6, but `__base__` is a python thing; alternatively you could do `t.__bases__[0]`

Comment: This does work for me now... not sure what I did wrong before. But I think a safer and better way would be: `t=type(obj); if hasattr(t, '_deferred') and t._deferred: t = t._meta.proxy_for_model`

Comment: `_deferred` is also set on regular models; but in any case, you can use the 3-arg getattr: `getattr(t, '_deferred', False)`

Answer (score 6):

On the deferred class, you can also get the original class without manipulating the `__class__.__name__` string using:

```
obj._meta.concrete_model
'product.models.ProductModelName'

obj._meta.concrete_model._meta.app_label
'product'

obj._meta.concrete_model._meta.model_name
'productmodelname'
```

Answer (score 0):

In django 1.4 the deferred class is constructed like this:

```
def deferred_class_factory(model, attrs):
    """
    Returns a class object that is a copy of "model" with the specified "attrs"
    being replaced with DeferredAttribute objects. The "pk_value" ties the
    deferred attributes to a particular instance of the model.
    """
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = model._meta.app_label

    # The app_cache wants a unique name for each model, otherwise the new class
    # won't be created (we get an old one back). Therefore, we generate the
    # name using the passed in attrs. It's OK to reuse an existing class
    # object if the attrs are identical.
    name = "%s_Deferred_%s" % (model.__name__, '_'.join(sorted(list(attrs))))
    name = util.truncate_name(name, 80, 32)

    overrides = dict([(attr, DeferredAttribute(attr, model))
            for attr in attrs])
    overrides["Meta"] = Meta
    overrides["__module__"] = model.__module__
    overrides["_deferred"] = True
    return type(name, (model,), overrides)
```

So, theoretically you should get at the real class by doing

```
type(type(deferred))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access to , `obj.__class__`

```
  >>> print obj.__class__
  <class 'product.models.Product_Deferred_name'>
  >>> print obj.__class__.__name__
  Product_Deferred_name
  >>> print obj.__class__.__name__.split("_")[0]
  Product
```

If your model name contain `_`,

```
  >>> print obj.__class__.__name__.replace("_Deferred_name","")
  Product
```

Comment: That doesn't work, you'll end up with `<class 'product.models.Product_Deferred_content'>`

Comment: try, obj.__class__.__name__

Comment: still doesn't work. I want to end up with `<class 'product.models.Product'>`, not `<class 'product.models.Product_Deferred_name'>`

Comment: come on... using split like that seems like too much of a hack, no? What if I had an underscore in the model's name?

Comment: then, try like this -- print p.__class__.__name__.replace("_Deferred_name","") -- :D